# How to print (hardcopy) with folds in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have a very simple todo list with dates and tags :

```
141218 Call school &phone @me
141219 Buy groceries &buy @me
141220 Have W order books &buy @W
141220 Think about vacation &vac @me
141221 Have W try Santa Claus outfit &fam @W
141222 Ask a question to S.O. &vim @me
```

This list is not long (I have much longer files in mind), but suppose I want to print it, and only print, e.g., the @W part ?

First I shall search :

```
/&W
```

then fold (Vim Wikia Simple Folding : Tip 282)

```
:set foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)!~@/
:nnoremap <F8> :set foldmethod=expr<CR><Bar>zM
```

I now have :

```
+—- 2 lines
141220 Have W order books &buy @W
+—- 1 line
141221 Have W try Santa Claus outfit &fam @W
+—- 1 line
```

This works fine down to the hardcopy part : all lines are displayed…

How should I proceed to print this folded file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `:hardcopy` doesn't consider the current representation in the window, it prints the physical contents (and also has other limitations, like ignoring concealment).

#### Use another means of printing

The `:TOhtml` command ships with Vim, and can create a HTML representation of the current window, including folds. You can then print that HTML file from the browser.

#### (Temporarily) remove the lines instead of folding

You can do so with the `:global` command:

```
:global!/@W/delete _
:hardcopy
:undo
```

Maybe as a custom command:

```
:command! -nargs=? HardcopyMatching execute 'global!/' . <q-args> . '/delete _' | hardcopy | undo
```

Comment: Thank you very much : it works fine (and I accepted the answer). But... I have some fear I might wreck my file during that process (call that vim-clumsiness...). Is it possible to "pass" that search (@W) to a function which I could call with a simple mapping ? Thanks again for your very fast answer.

Comment: I could not make it work. I must be botching something. I searched /@W then I typed Enter, then went in command line and typed your custom command. Nothing came out. Any idea of what went wrong ? Sorry to bother you...

Comment: To be clear: the above has to be put into `~/.vimrc` to make it permanent, or type it in once. Then use `:HardcopyMatching @W`. Or leave off the `@W`, and it'll default to the last search pattern.